# Trying to output fieldname/Columnname from Model passed to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So in my View (i'm not using Razor) but i'm trying to write out fieldnames from my Model Schema (not the data). So i try :

```
<%  
        foreach (var item in Model.ExportToExcel.AsQueryable())
               {


                   Response.Write(item); <!-- I want like item[0].name. I can get data easy, i.e. item.<fieldname> this works -->

               }
%>
```

If I debug this View I can see from the POP UP intellisense that all teh fieldnames as well as the DATA are there. I cannot seem to reference in code though

Must be doing something stupid - any comments appreciated

I have this controller code:

```
public IQueryable<rptExportToExcelResult> GetExportToExcelStructure()
{
    var result = this._lmsDb.rptExportToExcel();

    return result.AsQueryable();

}
```

Comment: How was the last edit accepted...it removed the code?

Comment: if I debug and goto IMMEDIATE window I can only get data, see below :

Comment: ?item[0]
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Lms.Model.rptExportToExcelResult'
?item
{Lms.Model.rptExportToExcelResult}
    _Agreement_Active: "No"
    _Agreement_AgreementType: "Turbine Lease"
    _Agreement_Comments: null
    _Agreement_EndDate: {17/08/2019 00:00:00}
    _Agreement_NoOfTurbines: 3

Comment: Is the problem IQueryable cannot output fieldname, has no property but confusing since its in the object but cannot be referenced

Answer (score 1):

`<%: item.name %>` should work for this, `response.write` isn't used in MVC.

Take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) for the syntax for outputting values onto the view.

**Edit Based on your comments:**

Your view would usually contain a model at the top of the page like `@model IEnumerable<modelName>`, and you would then use...

```
foreach (var item in Model)
 --in here output model properties, i.e. item.PropertyName
```

Your controller would look like...

```
public ActionResult ViewName()
{
    return View(Model);//the model might be a List<> of items.
}
```

but, as I said in the comment, take a look at [MVC getting started](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: No joy with that I get " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference"

Comment: @John, please show the view and the model (`ExportToExcel`) code. It looks like the model has no property `name`

Comment: I've updated Question content. Now I can see data ok, intelisense coming up on item object in the VIew with all the fieldnames but I want fieldnames, not data

Comment: Does your `view` have a `@model...` at the top of the page? Your controller should return a 'View(model)' as an `ActionResult`, your setup above looks confusing.  I think it's worth you looking here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials to see how the model binding works.